# Can main method return error code if program crashes?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, error-code

I am wondering if the

```
public static void main (String args [])
```

can return any error code if the program crashes? And if not, why is this so? Is it only because of the return type void? If I were to change the return type to something else, would it then be able to return error code?

I have naturally searched the Internet for this and I am sure someone has asked something similarly, but I still don't really understand the reason behind it.

Comment: To set the process exit code you can use `java.lang.System.exit(int)` call.

Comment: You cannot change the return type of that main method or the JVM will produce an error: `Error: Main method must return a value of type void`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can return any error code if the program crashes?

No, since the return type is `void`.

But exiting a Java program doesn't happen when the main method returns. It happens when the last non-daemon thread stops, or when `System.exit()` is called. And `System.exit()` takes an integer as argument. So if you want your Java process to end with status 42, all you need to do is call `System.exit(42)`.